# Retrieving related data in the Symfony Admin Generator

Tags: symfony1, admin, generator

I have a problem with the Admin Generator. The Table of Pages have the column `sf_guard_user_id`. The rest of the table looks as this part of the `generator.yml` in the line display,

```
list:
  title: Pages
  display:      [=title, sfGuardUser, views, state, privacy, created_at, updated_at]
  sort:         [created_at, desc]
  fields:
    sfGuardUser: { label: Author }
    created_at:  { label: Published, date_format: dd.MM.y }
    updated_at:  { label: Updated, date_format: dd.MM.y }
  table_method: retrieveUserList
```

Now the `sf_guard_user_id` is been replaced and the username ist displayed. Don't get me wrong, that works fine. But how can I get other variables from the `sfGuarsUser` relation? When I only add salt or another variable to display I get this,

```
Unknown record property / related component "salt" on "simplePage"
```

But why?

Answer (score 3):

The name of the user gets displayed because the `_toString()` of the `sfGuardUser` class returns the username. And I guess the related name from `simplePage` to `sfGuardUser` is `sfGuardUser`.

But when you only specify `salt`, the generator looks up whether `simplePages` has such an property or not. The admin generator does not know that you mean the `salt` field of `sfGuardUser` (how should it?).

---

You can use **[partial fields](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/14-Generators#chapter_14_sub_fields)** to display that value. Therefore you have to specify the field with an **underscore** in front (`_salt`) e.g.:

```
display:      [=title, sfGuardUser, _salt, views, state, privacy, created_at, updated_at]
```

The output for `_salt` is determined by the **file** `modules/<your_module_name_here>/templates/_salt.php`.

In this file, you have access to the **current object** via a variable named by the name of your model class (`$simple_page` or `$simplePage`in your case).

So you can put following code into `_salt.php`:

```
<?php echo $simple_page->getGuardUser()->getSalt(); ?>
```

I am not sure about the `getGuardUser()` method but I guess you know how to access the associated user from your page model.

Answer (score 0):

The admin generator can't delve into related object properties with the default configuration.

The reason that your sfGuardUser field is displaying correctly is because Doctrine defined a `getSfGuardUser` method in your 'page' class when it was told the two objects were related and the admin generator calls that function to display its column (technically calling the __toString() method on the resulting 'sfGuardUser' object returned by the method).

To get a property of one of your object's related models you can either define a custom getter in your page object:

```
public function getSfGuardUserSalt() {
  return $this['sfGuardUser']['salt'];
}
```

and then reference that in your generator.yml:

```
display: [title, sfGuardUser, sfGuardUserSalt, ...]
```

or create a partial to handle your custom rendering:

modules/pages/templates/_sfGuardUser.php:

```
<?php echo $page['sfGuardUser']['name']; ?><br />
<?php echo $page['sfGuardUser']['salt']; ?>
```

and then include it in your generator.yml with a preceding underscore:

```
display: [title, _sfGuardUser, views, ...]
```